# API to manage Azure database firewall whitelist

Tags: azure-sql-database

We have a large library of client databases which our clients need to connect directly to. At the moment we manually whitelist ranges for them, it is becoming difficult with some clients because they need to move around a lot and access from different IPs.

There is a web API, but one of our interfaces needs to connect directly (legacy desktop app), and it will be years before this is migrated, so direct access is necessary.

We can of course set up accounts and grant specific access, but the firewall exclusion process is just another learning task for users in the Azure UI, and they couldn't be bothered which causes a heavy support load.

As an option, we are considering creating a simplified UI where the user is 2FA authenticated, and it just adds their current IP to the whitelist. What are our options to do this - is there an Azure API we could do this through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure REST API has this ability - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/2020-11-01-preview/firewallrules/createorupdate?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259#uri-parameters) for the part for SQL Database Firewall Rules